# Angular translate Pipe could not be found

Tags: angular, translation

I have a component that uses the translateService, but it's not possible to translate items with the pipe on the Component Template HTML, i get following error:

> The pipe 'translate' could not be found

app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpModule, Http} from "@angular/http";
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader} from 'ng2-translate';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpModule,
TranslateModule.forRoot({
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, './assets/i18n', '.json'),
    deps: [Http]
   })
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

booking.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BookingComponent} from './booking.component';
import {TranslateService} from 'ng2-translate';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-booking',
   templateUrl: './booking.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./booking.component.css']
})

export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService
  ) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('de');
    translate.use('de');
};

ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

booking.component.html

```
<p>{{'TESTKEY' | translate }}</p>
```

The translation with the service on the component works fine, but i need to translate also the html with pipe

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You need to `imports: [ TranslateModule ]` into whatever module the `BookingComponent` is declare in. The import in the app module only makes the pipes available to components declared in that module. But providers/services are globally registered from the module (unlike components, directives, and pipes)

Comment: You can import a module what contains TransalateModule too. I used  `imports: [ SharedModule, //<- This module contains Imports:[TranslateModule] XYZModule ]`

Answer (score 31):

For those coming across this, here are the steps you need to do in a nutshell to fix the issue

1. Have the translate module logic along with translate loader and translateFactory present in the app.module.ts

```
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (http: Http) => 
        new TranslateStaticLoader(http, './assets/i18n', '.json'),
        deps: [Http]
       })
    ],`
```

1. In your shared.module.ts (or any other module), import and export the Translate module. 
   i.e.: Translate module should be a part of both the import and export arrays. Most answers in SO and github mention importing the module but not exporting it.

```
    @NgModule({
     imports: [
       // other imported modules here
       TranslateModule
    ],
    exports: [
    // other exported modules here
    TranslateModule]`
```

Comment: The documentation only suggests having to export **TranslateModule** when using a **SharedModule**. There is no mention of having to add to the exports of the root module (I.e. AppModule).  
Though adding to exports got the **translate** pipe working for me.   
Reference in ngx-translate docs:  
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#1-import-the-translatemodule

Comment: export the module allow using pipe in other modules than shared; conversely, import the module in shared allow to use it and it's pipe _in shared module_.

Comment: there is no need of exporting TranslateModule. its only for components to be shared out of that module.only importing works. tested in angular11 project #2021

Comment: THANK YOU, it worked! My "translate" pipe was not working in the child module, adding also export fixed that for whatever reason.

Answer (score 8):

I had that issue only on a single "page". If the declaration for the component containing the translate pipe is missing, it will also not find it.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: InventoryPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedComponentModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    InventoryPage // << Check your declaration
  ]
})
export class InventoryPageModule {}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am working with Ionic 5. My HTML in home.page.html

```
<h2 > {{'HOME.title' | translate }}</h2>
```

I had the error

> The pipe 'translate' could not be found

marked in red error in Visual Studio Code. But the Ionic App was compiling with ionic serve anyway and the translation was working.

Anyway I managed to remove the error. As already mentioned above some guides do not stress that it is important to export also the module. In my case in home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core'; //IMPORT THE MODULE IN ANY PAGE 

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule     //IMPORT THE MODULE
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage],
  exports:[TranslateModule],     //REMEMBER TO ADD THIS TO EXPORT IT AS WELL!!!
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I was facing the same error, Add TranslateModule in your respective module. Also, make sure your you have added the below points.

app.module.ts
Outside of class:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

Inside imports:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
}}),
```

Sub Module - imports:

```
TranslateModule
```

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Translate Module: to use translator as a pipe (on template)

```
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

imports: [
CommonModule,
RouterModule, //Router Module
TranslateModule //Translate Module**
```

]

Answer (score 1):

A simple restart of Visual Studio Code resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I want to know if your solution was true when you compile the app with ng build?

Answer (score 1):

i have spent a couple hours trying to fix this as well in a new project,
i'm using different multiple modules ( **app.module.ts** , **client.module.ts**, **admin.module.ts** )

i tried to import the **translateModule** everywhere but it never worked, until i figured out i didn't import **clientModule** and **adminModule** in my **app.module.ts**.

pay attention to this :

```
  imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
RouterModule,
ClientModule, // make sure this is imported
ClientRoutingModule,
AdminModule,  // make sure this is imported
AdminRoutingModule,
SharedModule
],
 exports: [
SharedModule  // where i imported my TranslateModule
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I had been using an incompatible version of @ngx-translate/core that was not suitable for my Angular version. I recommend referring to the following table, which outlines the compatibility of each Angular version:
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core
Ensure you install the version that aligns with the specific Angular version you are utilizing.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more possible problem. If you work with newer versions of `angular` and `ngx-translate`, if you have 'Use legacy View Engine' checked in settings, then `vs code` will underline translate pipe with red showing that it cannot find it, though translations will work when app is running. So just uncheck this option and everyhting will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the translate module within a lazy loaded module of angular, you need to add the TranslateModule import to module.ts file within the lazy loaded file as well. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use standalone project (Angular 15+) you configuration should look like this:

First install `@ngx-translate/core` and `@ngx-translate/http-loader` dependencies

In `app.config.ts`

```
//import
//...
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';


export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
  importProvidersFrom(
    //...
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
      deps: [HttpClient]
    }
   }))
  ]
};
```

In your component ts file

```
@Component({
  //...
  standalone: true,
  imports: [/*other imports,*/ TranslateModule],
  //...
})
export class YourComponent {
  //...
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  //...
  }
 //...
}
```

And to finish just add your translation file in assets/i18n folder.

Here is code [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zwbogk?file=src%2Fapp.config.ts) on Stackblitz.

Hope it could be helpful